# click on input box to show open file dialog but not click on choose file button

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have an input box and I want user to click on the input box to show the open file dialog and show the filename in the same input box. But if I use the input type="file", it will show the "choose file button", I dont wan to show the button. How can I do it?

html:

```
<div class="fileupload">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
</div>

<div class="fileupload">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="attachement" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EctCK/
** I dont wan this, how do I hide the choose file button?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can overlay a transparent `<input type="file"/>` over a styled button or other element.

```
<input type="file" style="opacity:0;"/>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/VH9yt/) for a working demo.

Comment: this is a really creative hack!

Comment: or you can call the click() method of a non-displayed <input> within the div's onclick() for better croos-and-old-browser compatibility

Comment: @SuperScipt how about if I don't want the open file dialog but instead the Save As dile dialog?

Comment: @bleykFaust that's a totally different question, try searching around for content-disposition or data-URIs.

Comment: @SuperScript thanks but can you give me a sample if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: @AnilPanwar this is my question im asking you a while ago

Comment: The fiddle is no longer available `404`

Comment: @pathros oops, my bad; thanks for letting me know.  I've updated it to the new url.

Answer (score 7):

Well there is a little hack for this. You do need to have file upload control on the page. But you can hide it and simulate the file upload control using any other control like div/span/button and style it as you want. Here is a working sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/zCcmd/).

HTML:

```
<div id="dummy" class="dummyDiv"> 
    <span>click to chose file:</span> 
    <span id="fileName" class="yellow"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="flupld" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#dummy").click(function () {
    $("#flupld").click();
});

$("#flupld").change(function () {
    //file input control returns the file path as C:\fakepath\<file name>
    //on windows, so we remeove it and show only file name.
    var file=$(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/ig,'');

    $("#fileName").text(file);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to pre-select a filename? That is to say, when the dialog is open, one sees a "suggested" filename

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none">
   <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').click(); return false;"> Upload </a>
```

Working sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parseh/42Ldgac0/)