# jQuery detect when clicking on browse with file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect the action when clicking on the browse on this form?

```
<form action='#' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='file'>  
</form>
```

I have another div and when I click on that div I want that the browse action will happen

Comment: Not as easy as it sounds, but quite doable, still a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878854/open-file-dialog-when-input-type-button, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310450/click-on-input-box-to-show-open-file-dialog-but-not-click-on-choose-file-button

Comment: Thank you, one of the answers below got me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uye85kyk/), it is as simple as

```
$( "#file" ).click( function(){

   alert(1);

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out:
When clicking on the div that I want to trigger it for example `#my_div`, The `input class` will be clicked

```
$("#my_div").click(function() {
    $("input_class").click();
})
```